# iphone childbrowser cordova :: Unable to load 2nd webpage

Tags: iphone, phonegap-plugins

I am using ChildBrowser phonegap(Cordova) plugin, downloaded from [Github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins)

So far i am able to load my external page www.xyz.com/login.aspx, which has login id/pass and login button. Upon login button click with valid login data, my application should load www.xyz.com/tasks.aspx page. But blank screen is displayed. Please help to load correct page.

In log i can see following texts

```
New Address is : http://xyz.com/login.aspx
New Address is : http://xyz.com/tasks.aspx
```

but content of tasks.aspx is not displayed.

Has anyone faced such issue, or its plugin issue (if so, how to get fixed code from github?)

Answer (score 0):

In my case Child browser is working fine , If you can able to navigate to "tasks.aspx" from login.aspx . I think in your coding wise no issue , if this page usage any flash content it will show blank , can you check this again.